# How can I calculate center of mass after floodfill?

Tags: image-processing

I have an image like this one [image]

with 3 distinct regions. Using a breath first 4 neighbor queue, I have implemented a basic flood fill that distinguishes between the 3.
Now I need to find the center of mass of these regions with each pixel weighing one unit of weight.
Whats the best way of going about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to keep three arrays, `sumx`, `sumy` and `count`, each with one entry per label (3 in your case), and all initialized to 0. Then run through the image once, and for each labeled pixel add the x coordinate to the corresponding bin in `sumx`, the y coordinate to the corresponding bin in `sumy`, and 1 to the corresponding bin in `count`.

At the end, for each label `l` you can compute `sumx[l]/count[l]` and `sumy[l]/count[l]`. These are the unweighted centers of gravity (centroids).